Write encoding settings in the metadata of libaom
In x264 I have automatically saved the encoding settings like crf in the metadata of the container file after encoding. How can I get the same behavior in libaom?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
